# Can multiple Combo boxes and Push buttons have same object name

Tags: python, pyqt

I have multiple combo boxes in my QT project in four different tabs, on selecting them a general function has to be run. My question is, can multiple combo boxes and Push buttons have same object name. So that I can generalize my code instead of writing separate code to each Push button or Combo box.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are currently doing?

Comment: I have four tab widget,each tab contains comboboxes and Pushbuttons. The functionality of each combo box and Push button are same. So can I use same object name for multiple push buttons so that I can use the same object name everywhere in the code.